# Continue an aborted AJAX (jqXHR) request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototype, jqxhr

Is it possible to continue an aborted AJAX (jqXHR) request?

Something like:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
  if(/* it enters my conditions */) {
    $.current_request = jQuery.extend(true, {}, jqXHR);
    jqXHR.abort();
  }
}

// some time in the future
$.ajax($.current_request)
```

This is not working, and I can see one problem that I do not know how to solve: no options are set when sending the request again.

Comment: I don't think you can. But why are you aborting every request like that? What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps it's solvable with [promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: HTTP requests, including AJAX calls, are not stateful - that is, there's nothing stored anywhere once the request ends. I can't see how you could restart an aborted request, but unless there's data being sent to the server there's nothing to stop you sending the whole request again.

Comment: store the options, then make a new request with said options. However, you're ajaxSend will just abort it again.

Comment: Yes, I have several conditions inside ajaxSend, to only catch the ones I want. @KevinB how exactly can I make a request with the options?

Comment: `$.ajax(theoptions)` They're currently stored in the ajaxOptions parameter, you'll have to store that somewhere globally to access it later (such as in `$.current_request`)

Comment: You are correct Sir @KevinB! Seems I was over-thinking it, I can even discard the $.current_request var as it is totally useless now :D

Comment: Note that you can also avoid aborting the request at all by instead using a pre-filter to modify the options, depending on what exactly it is you are doing of course.

Comment: I need to insert some aditional parameters (password, etc.) input by the user. But I can't use JS's native prompt box, so all of this is non-blocking, which complicates a bit.

Comment: Those additional parameters can be added using the pre-filter i mentioned. That's actually what the prefilter is for. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/

Comment: @KevinB the problem is that I have to stop the request from executing until the user inputs the password. Since this is a non-blocking operation, I can't use the pre-filter.

Comment: why not... just not send the request until you have said information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$.ajax(theoptions)`
>
> They're currently stored in the ajaxOptions parameter, you'll have to store that somewhere globally to access it later (such as in $.current_request) – Kevin B

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try (not tested)

```
var request_queue = [], is_processing = false;
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions){
    if(/* it enters my conditions */) {
        jqXHR.abort();
        request_queue.push(ajaxOptions);
    }
    else if (request_queue.length && !is_processing) {
        is_processing = true;
        while (ajaxOptions = request_queue.shift())
        {
            $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
        }
        is_processing = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes the issue was on using ``ajaxOptions`` to build the new request, as pointed out by Kevin B here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837293/continue-an-aborted-ajax-jqxhr-request/18837590#comment27790439_18837293