# Can we stop sending ajax for a while and continue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, alert, actionlink, bootbox, unobtrusive-ajax

I need to stop sending ajax request of an **Ajax.ActionLink** for a while on **OnBegin** and **continue** the request if confirm alert is true. In below code i could abort ajax request, is there any way to resend it using its own methods.

```
beforeDelete: function (x, y) {
    x.abort();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?", function (result) {
        if (result) { 
          //process again
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit:**
I have achieved it, Thanks Guruprasad.

```
var prevDel = true;
function beforeDelete(x, y) {
    if (prevDel) {
        x.abort();
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?", function (result) {
            if (result) {
                prevDel = false;
                $.ajax(y);
            } else {
                prevDel = true;
            }
        });
    } else {
        prevDel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: **[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837293/continue-an-aborted-ajax-jqxhr-request)** might help you

Answer (score 0):

Ok... You could break up the code:

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?", function (result) {
        if (result) { 
          //send ajax request from here
        }
    });
```

Comment: i m seeking for methods like abort() to resend request..i already know about writing a new ajax code