# AJAX continue/resume after abort

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Hello guys,**

i would like to ask if there is any possibility to continue aborted ajax.  I got arraz of ajax calls in defferreds like this:

```
var defferreds = [];
defferreds.push(
    $soap.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "some_url.php",
        cache: false,    
    }).done(function(data) {
        /* do something */ 
    }).fail(function(jqXHR,status, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    })
);
```

There are like 20 more ajax(es) in the defferreds array. When user clicks on abort_ajax button, it should abort all ajaxes that are not done yet. I use this function to do so:

```
function abort_ajaxes(){
    for(var i = 0; i < defferreds.length; i++){
        if(defferreds[i] && defferreds[i].readyState != 4){
            defferreds[i].abort();
        } else {
            delete defferreds[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Here goes the part where i need your help. As soon as user clicks on resume_ajax button, it should call the remaining ajaxes out of the defferreds array and complete them. The problem is, that i dont have a clue how to start aborted ajax even though i have it stored in my array of defferreds. **Is it possible to resume aborted ajaxes? And only those which were aborted and not the ones that have succesfuly ended?**

**EDIT:** 
Im asking if there is possibility to rerun only not completed ajaxes. I tried the solution that is used in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837293/continue-an-aborted-ajax-jqxhr-request), but it does not solve my concrete problem. Once i click on resume_ajax button nothing happens even though i used this code :

```
$('.resume_ajax').click(function(){
    for (var key in defferreds){
        $soap.ajax(defferreds[key]);
    }
});
```

**What is the exact line of code that calls aborted ajaxes again? Can it even be achieved with ajax call looking like one in my defferreds array? Because as i said, nothing happened.**

EDIT2:

I run the ajaxes like this:

```
function run_ajaxes(){
    var defferreds = [];
    /* there are around 20 same ajax calls just with another url */
    defferreds.push(
        $soap.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "some_url.php",
            cache: false,    
        }).done(function(data) {
            /* do something */ 
        }).fail(function(jqXHR,status, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
        })
    );
}

$('.run_ajaxes').click(function(){
    run_ajaxes();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continue an aborted AJAX (jqXHR) request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837293/continue-an-aborted-ajax-jqxhr-request)

Comment: I think you have to pass the ajax options again and re run it.

Comment: Since you have an array, you can store the status of each ajax in your array. So you can detect the aborted ones and call them again...

Comment: @EhsanT but how do i call them again? Can you please tell me what can i do to call those ajaxes that are aborted from the array again?

Comment: @maheshiv how do i do that please?

Comment: How are you running them right now? I mean all of them

Comment: @EhsanT i edited the question so you can see how i am calling the ajaxes. Thank you in advance for your help, im really desperate.

Comment: [restart ajax after network abort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59051072/10264874)

Comment: Refer the offline js simplest solution [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59051072/10264874)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a very simple solution for you. Here I have one `outpu` div for progress reporting, and two buttons, `abort` which when it is clicked will abort all still running requests, and `continue` button, which will resume the execution of aborted requests.

To test the solution, press the `continue` button first. I used https://httpbin.org/delay mockup server for mocking the requests. Than press `abort` button while there are still some running requests. And than press `continue` button again - this will start the execution of all undone requests.Here is the code

```js
var output = $("#output");
var ajaxes = [];
var count = 10;

// Function which will run the ajax call
function run(idx) {
  // Get the ajax args
  var args = $.extend({}, ajaxes[idx]);
  
  // Run the ajax and replace the args with ajax deferred
  ajaxes[idx] = $.ajax(args)
    .done(function() {
     $(output.find("p")[idx]).html("done");
    })
    .fail(function() {
     $(output.find("p")[idx]).html("aborted");
      // Replace the ajax deferred with the original ajax args
      ajaxes[idx] = args;
    });
}

for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  // Create output element to report progress for each ajax call
  output.append("<p>sleeping</p>");
  
  // Custom delayed response 
  var delay = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  
  // Create ajax arguments
  var args = {
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://httpbin.org/delay/" + delay
  };
  
  // Store the ajax args
  ajaxes[i] = args;
}

$("#abort").on("click", function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   // Abort each undone ajax call
    if(ajaxes[i].readyState != 4) {
      ajaxes[i].abort();
    }
  }
});

$("#continue").on("click", function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   // Run all ajax call that where not finished yet
    if(!ajaxes[i].readyState) {
     $(output.find("p")[i]).html("... loading");
      run(i);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="continue">continue</button>
<button id="abort">abort</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```