# Resume or restart ajax request after network connection abort while uploading large images?

Tags: ajax, amazon-s3, restart, plupload, abort

I am trying to upload large files using PLUpload library.at fileUploaded function I have ajax call to upload image to Amazon S3 but ajax call fails prompting error network connection aborted.
Please help how to restart or resume my request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I detected the network is down or running perfectly fine using [offline js](https://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/)

```
var run = function(){        
         Offline.check();
    }

    setInterval(run, 3000);
```

check every 3 seconds network connection available or not.

when network goes up after re-connection perform action at up function

```
Offline.on('up', function(){
if(ajax_response === null || ajax_response == 'error')
{
    rename_file (oldname,newname)
}
});
```

store function parameters as global variables to use it for function call.

```
    var ajax_response = null;
window.rename_file = function(oldname,newname)
    {
        var resp =null;

        $.ajax({            
            url:'ajaxcall.php',
            data:{action:'rename_file',new_name:newname,old_name:oldname},  
            async:false,            
            success:function(data,status)
            {
                resp = 'success';
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {               
                resp = 'error';                 
            }
        });

        ajax_response.= resp;
        return resp;
    }
```