# Resume the Ajax upload form when the Internet is connected

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload, resumable

When the user's internet is connected, the upload is done and while uploading, the internet is suddenly disconnected and the form upload is failed.(status = (failed)net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED , Type = xhr)

Is there a code that resumes the upload form after connecting to the Internet?

This is my upload code that is sent as Ajax:

```
$('#form_upload_create').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$form = $(this)
var formData = new FormData(this);
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
           alert(response.message)
        }
    },
    xhr: function () {
        //upload Progress
        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
                var percent = 0;
                var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                var total = event.total;
                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                    percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                }
                //update progressbar
                $(".progress-bar").css("width", +percent + "%");
                $(".status").text(percent + "%" + 'waiting upload...');
            }, true);
        }
        return xhr;
    },
});
```

});

Comment: Hi, maybe this link can help you. Seems like the same issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975602/resume-or-restart-ajax-request-after-network-connection-abort-while-uploading-la

Comment: Hi dear friend
Unfortunately, this page suggestion that I gave you worked for a few hours did not work